# Tensorflow mean squared error loss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have seen a few different mean squared error loss functions in various posts for regression models in Tensorflow:

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(prediction - Y,2))/(n_instances)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(prediction, Y))
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(prediction - Y)
```

What are the differences between these?

Comment: [1-st and 2-nd do the same thing in theory, 3-rd is scaled by a constant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43830040/1090562)

Comment: One more way to compute MSE (equivalent to your 1st and 2nd method): [tf.losses.mean_squared_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say that the third equation is different, while the 1st and 2nd are formally the same but behave differently due to numerical concerns.

I think that the 3rd equation (using `l2_loss`) is just returning 1/2 of the squared Euclidean norm, that is, the sum of the element-wise square of the input, which is `x=prediction-Y`. You are not dividing by the number of samples anywhere. Thus, if you have a very large number of samples, the computation may overflow (returning Inf).

The other two are formally the same, computing the mean of the element-wise squared `x` tensor. However, while the documentation does not specify it explicitly, it is very likely that `reduce_mean` uses an algorithm adapted to avoid overflowing with very large number of samples. In other words, it likely does not try to sum everything first and *then* divide by N, but use some kind of rolling mean that can adapt to an arbitrary number of samples without necessarily causing an overflow.

Comment: "it is very likely that reduce_mean uses an algorithm adapted to avoid overflowing with very large number of samples" I don't think that this is true.  [here is the relevant code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3553486256ae68ac72ed1ed2688a055381d818a5/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/reduction_ops.cc#L102), and it is pretty clear that what you claim is happening is not happening.  Although, the tf code is something of a rabbithole, and I'm not an expert on the matter.  However, without some citation or evidence, I find some of these claims dubious.

Answer (score 16):

The first and the second loss functions calculate the same thing, but in a slightly different way. The third function calculate something completely different. You can see this by executing this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

shape_obj = (5, 5)
shape_obj = (100, 6, 12)
Y1 = tf.random_normal(shape=shape_obj)
Y2 = tf.random_normal(shape=shape_obj)

loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(Y1 - Y2, 2)) / (reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, shape_obj))
loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y1, Y2))
loss3 = tf.nn.l2_loss(Y1 - Y2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run([loss1, loss2, loss3])
# when I run it I got: [2.0291963, 2.0291963, 7305.1069]
```

Now you can verify that 1-st and 2-nd calculates the same thing (in theory) by noticing that `tf.pow(a - b, 2)` is the same as `tf.squared_difference(a - b, 2)`. Also `reduce_mean` is the same as `reduce_sum / number_of_element`. The thing is that computers can't calculate everything exactly. To see what numerical instabilities can do to your calculations take a look at this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

shape_obj = (5000, 5000, 10)
Y1 = tf.zeros(shape=shape_obj)
Y2 = tf.ones(shape=shape_obj)

loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(Y1 - Y2, 2)) / (reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, shape_obj))
loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y1, Y2))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run([loss1, loss2])
```

It is easy to see that the answer should be 1, but you will get something like this: `[1.0, 0.26843545]`.

Regarding your last function, the documentation says that:

> Computes half the L2 norm of a tensor without the sqrt: output = sum(t
>   ** 2) / 2

So if you want it to calculate the same thing (in theory) as the first one you need to scale it appropriately:

```
loss3 = tf.nn.l2_loss(Y1 - Y2) * 2 / (reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, shape_obj))
```

Comment: So does this mean that the built in tensorflow function is worse than is you explicitly calculate the square and take the mean? This doesn't make sense to me, Shouldn't the built in implementation be more numerically stable? otherwise why go to the trouble of making a function anyway?

Comment: So what is the use case of `tf.nn.l2_loss`?