# An Efficient way to Calculate loss function batchwise?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bigdata

I am using autoencoders to do anomaly detection. So, I have finished training my model and now I want to calculate the reconstruction loss for each entry in the dataset. so that I can assign anomalies to data points with high reconstruction loss.

This is my current code to calculate the reconstruction loss 
But this is really slow. By my estimation, it should take 5 hours to go through the dataset whereas training one epoch occurs in approx 55 mins.
 I feel that converting to tensor operation is bottlenecking the code, but I can't find a better way to do it.

I've tried changing the batch sizes but it does not make much of a difference. I have to use the convert to tensor part because K.eval is throwing an error if I do it normally.

python

```
 for i in range(0, encoded_dataset.shape[0], batch_size):    
    y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(encoded_dataset[i:i+batch_size].values,
 np.float32)
     y_pred= tf.convert_to_tensor(ae1.predict(encoded_dataset[i:i+batch_size].values),
 np.float32)
    # Append the batch losses (numpy array) to the list
    reconstruction_loss_transaction.append(K.eval(loss_function( y_true, y_pred)))
```

I was able to train in 55 mins per epoch. So I feel prediction should not take 5 hours per epoch. encoded_dataset is a variable that has the entire dataset in main memory as a data frame.
I am using Azure VM instance.
`K.eval(loss_function(y_true,y_pred)` is to find the loss for each row of the batch 
So y_true will be of size `(batch_size,2000)` and so will y_pred
`K.eval(loss_function(y_true,y_pred)` will give me an output of

> `(batch_size,1)` evaluating binary cross entropy on each row of y
>   _true and y_pred

Comment: I've deleted my previous answer, can you edit your question to explain what `K.eval(loss_function( y_true, y_pred))` is then? I'm confused about what we're looking at there.

Comment: i have made the changes .

Comment: How is it that `ae1.predict` takes the same data as `y_true`? Both take as input `encoded_dataset[i:i+batch_size].values`. If you perform prediction you would pass in the input data, but it seems like you're predicting using labels. I assume then that `values` contains both data and labels in some way that's not obvious from the code snippet. In that case you're probably moving around the full input data multiple times. However it's not very clear.

Comment: I'm using an auto encoder model . So in the case of auroencoders you are trying the reconstruct the input using a neural network . That's why y_true uses the same value as y_pred

Comment: Ah, of course, brainfart, sorry.  My suspicion is that `ae1.predict` and `K.eval(loss_function` are behaving in unexpected ways. `ae1.predict` should normally be used to output the loss function value as well as `y_pred`.  When you create the model, specify that the loss value is another output (you can have a list of multiple outputs), then just call predict here once to get both `y_pred` the loss value in one call.

Comment: Ohh alright . Thanks ,But I want the loss for each row . Won't the loss returned by the predict method be the mean loss for the entire batch ?

Comment: Excellent question. The answer depends on how the loss function is implemented. Both ways produce perfectly valid and identical results in TF under the hood. You could average the loss over the batch before taking the gradient w.r.t. the loss, or take the gradient w.r.t. a vector of losses. The gradient operation in TF will perform the averaging of the losses for you if you use the latter approach (see SO articles on taking the per-batch gradient, it's actually hard to do).

Comment: If keras implements the loss with `reduce_mean` built into the loss, you could just define your own loss. If you're using square loss, replacing `'mean_squared_error'` with `lambda y_true, y_pred: tf.square(y_pred - y_true)`. That would produce square error instead of MSE (no diff to the gradient), but look here for the variant including the mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338509. In any case this produces a per sample loss so long as you don't use `tf.reduce_mean`, which is purely optional in the loss. Let me know if that resolves it and I'll move the discussion to an answer.

Comment: This has pretty much resolved it . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comments:

My suspicion is that `ae1.predict` and `K.eval(loss_function)` are behaving in unexpected ways. `ae1.predict` should normally be used to output the loss function value as well as `y_pred`. When you create the model, specify that the loss value is another output (you can have a list of multiple outputs), then just call predict here once to get both `y_pred` the loss value in one call.

> But I want the loss for each row . Won't the loss returned by the predict method be the mean loss for the entire batch?

The answer depends on how the loss function is implemented. Both ways produce perfectly valid and identical results in TF under the hood. You could average the loss over the batch before taking the gradient w.r.t. the loss, or take the gradient w.r.t. a vector of losses. The gradient operation in TF will perform the averaging of the losses for you if you use the latter approach (see [SO articles on taking the per-sample gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080929/is-it-possible-to-compute-per-example-gradients-efficiently-in-tensorflow-in-ju), it's actually hard to do).

If Keras implements the loss with `reduce_mean` built into the loss, you could just define your own loss. If you're using square loss, replacing 'mean_squared_error' with lambda y_true, y_pred: tf.square(y_pred - y_true). That would produce square error instead of MSE (no difference to the gradient), but [look here for the variant including the mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338509).

In any case this produces a per sample loss so long as you don't use `tf.reduce_mean`, which is purely optional in the loss. Another option is to simply compute the loss separately from what you optimize for and make that an output of the model, also perfectly valid.